# How to make cursor for user touch in as3 for android?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

this code for muse
How to make cursor for user touch in as3 for android ?

```
 import flash.events.Event;
// listen out for the ENTER_FRAME event.
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveOurMouse);

// hide the real mouse
Mouse.hide();

// show where the function we made when we made our event listener
function moveOurMouse(event:Event) {

// make our custom cursor's position equal the real mouse's position
Shave.x = root.mouseX;
Shave.y = root.mouseY;

}
stop();
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. (What are you trying to do? What's the expected result and what's the actual result?)

Comment: So you want some sort of graphical object to appear on the form that mimics a mouse cursor? And that moves as the user moves their finger?

Comment: simply ...
How to make cursor for user touch in as3 for my android app i search about it and no useful result

Answer (score 1):

`root` is an as2 term. In as3 you can use `stage.mouseX` or `this.mouseX`